# Bluetooth Socket [isConnected()]

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I have 3 activities that uses Bluetooth Connection/Communication.

On my first page, I connect to a bluetooth device already. When I move to another activity, I tried using this code:

```
BluetoothSocket btSocket;

try{
if(btSocket.isConnected(){
   System.out.println("connected");
   }
}
catch (Exception e{
}
```

I did not get anything in my Logcat at all and the Activity did not crash too. I'm not sure on how to use a Thread/Runnable for this Bluetooth Connection to stay in connection through activities and such. So I was thinking if this is possible?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to be aware that `isConnected()` may or may not tell you whether the *connection* is valid in the case of `BluetoothSocket.` In the case of `java.net.Socket` it only tells you whether you ever connected *this socket.* It isn't the same thing. The documentation of `BluetoothSocket.isConnected()` is nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current approach seem to fail with an NullPointerException, which will be catched by your Exception-Block. I would suggest you to implement a Background service which will handle the BT-connection in background. A sample could be found on the bottom of this page: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html (Related Samples)

Comment: Is there any more in depth sample or example? I tried to follow the Bluetooth Low Energy and I couldn't really understand how to use the Service.

Comment: I meant the Bluetooth Chat example.

Comment: You will find the sample source e.g. in <<android sdk>>/samples/android-20/legacy/BluetoothChat on your local harddrive.

Comment: Ok thank you. I somehow got the idea  abit thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are ignoring the Exception that `btSocket` is null.

try

`catch (Exception e{  e.printStackTrace ();
}`

You will need to finad a way to pass you `active` Bluetooth connection to this method/activity.